# Using refresh token to get access token - 401 Permissions Missing

Tags: spotify

I am trying to set up a global access website that loads the access token when starting the node server. I ran spotify's example authentication app, and then saved that refresh token. Now, whenever I try to get a new access token using that refresh token, it gives me one, but when I try to use that access token, it says '401 - Permissions missing'. When I initially got the refresh token, I was using `'user-read-private user-read-email user-modify-playback-state'`

I am using the same client-id for both the example app and my app.

Here is the code: https//github.com/twinters007/SpotifyJukebox

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue.

I was trying to access https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player instead of           https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/